# Python: Why does my script on selenium only work if I am with that specific chrome tab open

Tags: python, selenium

so I am writing up a browser script with python using selenium, the code is supposed to click an image and reset the timer everytime the countdown is over (00:00), but the code only runs when I am on the selenium chrome browser, if I am using anything else in my pc the code just doesn't run (and it's only this specific part of code, I have some following code from the same page with different features that works fine with the selenium chrome browser minimized)

```
   def moving_on(self, energy):
        while True:
            #collectors
            if self.driver.find_element_by_id("farmers1").is_displayed():
                try:
                    if self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("countdown_amount").get_attribute("innerHTML") == '00:00':
                        self.driver.find_element_by_id("farmimage_1").click()
                        self.driver.find_element_by_id("farmimage_2").click()
                        self.driver.find_element_by_id("farmimage_3").click()
                        self.driver.find_element_by_id("farmimage_4").click()
                        self.driver.find_element_by_id("farmimage_5").click()
                        self.driver.implicitly_wait(1)
                        sleep(2)
                    else:
                        pass
                except:
                    pass
            else:
                sleep(1)
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please paste error message if log exist.

Comment: there's no error message since the script is still running, everything runs smoothly, it just doesnt click id="farmimage_1" unless I am on the Chrome tab, I have another feature that clicks and refills energy and that works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I list some possibilities;

```
   def moving_on(self, energy):
        while True:
            if self.driver.find_element_by_id("farmers1").is_displayed():
                try:
                    if self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("countdown_amount").get_attribute("innerHTML") == '00:00':
                        # (1) Perhaps, code may not step into this if clause. I recommend you to try logging here
                        # (2) Perhaps, there were multiple "farmimage_1" elements, if so selenium would click first element.
                        # (3) Selenium can't click element if the element not shown in the window
                        self.driver.find_element_by_id("farmimage_1").click()
                        self.driver.find_element_by_id("farmimage_2").click()
                        self.driver.find_element_by_id("farmimage_3").click()
                        self.driver.find_element_by_id("farmimage_4").click()
                        self.driver.find_element_by_id("farmimage_5").click()
                        self.driver.implicitly_wait(1)
                        sleep(2)
                    else:
                        pass
                except:
                    pass
            else:
                sleep(1)
```

Comment: I used logging and realize some part of my code was not returning to the "farmimage_1" part, thank you that helped me